# LeanFT null pointer at start

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, leanft

I have a problem with LeanFT. When i try to start it from intellij idea (LeanFT> Enable LeanFT) i have error:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ServerLauncher.runLauncherProcess(ServerLauncher.java:66)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ServerLauncher.launch(ServerLauncher.java:44)
    at com.hpe.lft.sdkUtilities.serverLaunch.ServerLaunchUtils.launchIfNeeded(ServerLaunchUtils.java:24)
    at com.hpe.lft.sdkUtilities.PluginServiceBase.launchServer(PluginServiceBase.java:129)
    at com.hpe.lft.sdkUtilities.PluginServiceBase.enableOrDisablePlugin(PluginServiceBase.java:105)
    at com.hpe.lft.actions.EnableLeanFTAction$1.run(EnableLeanFTAction.java:20)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Even if runtime engine start manually.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: Seems like problem with leanFT runtime engine. I cant start it from console with error "LeanFT runntime engine cannot be started. Conflicting process found".

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this same problem and it was to do with the LeanFT runtime unable to load NodeJS. Looking into it further my npm path was missing from the Windows environment variables. After adding the path to my npm installation it worked fine.

You may have a similar problem, but to find out the actual cause, I advise you to check the LeanFT runtime log file, which can be found here:

Configuration file:
`<LeanFT installation folder>\bin\LFTRuntime.log.config.xml`

Path to the log level:
`log4net > root`

(Change from "INFO" to "debug")

Log output:
`%localappdata%\Hewlett-Packard\LeanFT\Logs\HP.LeanFT.log`

More details on LeanFT logs can be found on [this HP support page](https://softwaresupport.softwaregrp.com/document/-/facetsearch/document/KM02539191).

Answer (score 0):

This could be multiple reasons...

1) Mostly LeanFT runtime agent issue. If you start LeanFT and disconnect from net, then LeanFT will not work properly as licensee server unavailability even after you connect net. Manually initiating LeanFT runtime also will not work. Either restarting Eclipse/intellij and restarting LeanFT run time will solve. Or restarting laptop/system while connected to net will solve this problem.

2) This problem arises when incompatible versions between LeanFT SDK's are used in script, IE/Chrome add-ons and Lean FT Runtime agent versions. Make sure everything is same version, like 14.0.2... Including minor versions.